# what does “blinking” mean in this sentence？

Tags: meaning

> Lucy found herself blinking in the light of a wood fire as soon as she got in.

Does “blinking” mean to look with half-shut eyes or to shine intermittently？

Comment: Did you think maybe the light was shining intermittently in this sentence? You may want to edit your question to clarify that so that someone might explain in their answer how they chose between the two definitions.

Comment: for [context](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=7YYhHvuNNzIC&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=Lucy+found+herself+blinking+in+the+light+of+a+wood+fire+as+soon+as+she+got+in.&source=bl&ots=JTvS5QTd2n&sig=ACfU3U2m1yVxMT7v49RBki1KXgoX7b3aLw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKvcW504jjAhUvE6YKHfG4CYYQ6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=Lucy%20found%20herself%20blinking%20in%20the%20light%20of%20a%20wood%20fire%20as%20soon%20as%20she%20got%20in.&f=false) This is from *The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe*, and describing Lucy walking into a cave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case "[to blink](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/blink)" means "to close and open the eyes quickly" – and probably involuntarily.

Most likely, Lucy is blinking because her eyes became accustomed to darkness before she entered this place with the wood fire. (It's possible that she is blinking in surprise, or that her eyes are irritated by the smoke, but the explicit reference to the fire's light strongly implies that the light is the cause of her blinking.)

Answer (score 0):

The first sense of "blinking" as given by [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/blinking) is

> to open and close the eye, especially involuntarily; wink rapidly and repeatedly.

I believe that this sense is intended here, although additional context would be helpful. Another sense is:

> to look with winking or half-shut eyes

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blink) gives similar definitions.